# which time format is used in optaplanner for the vehicle routing problem time windowed with JSON file

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

I use JSON file exists in example in optaplanner for the vehicle routing problem time windowed, but I have a problem with time window format. What is the best format recognized by this file?
thank you.

I tried hours format, the window time is well represented on the graph, but the solution is not optimal, then I tried minutes and seconds format, the time windows is not represented on the graph.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples's old vehicle-routing implementation use measureless numbers for service duration and travel time. Not durations/time. That's messy in the real world.

The new [vehicle-routing-time-windows quickstart](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/vehicle-routing-time-windows) in Timefold (fork of OptaPlanner, also open source) uses ISO formatted times and durations. Travel time is calculated by haversine. It has curl instructions to get a sample JSON file (look for the Guide link in the top).